# Using quantmod periodReturn with an index of variables in the environment

Tags: r, object, environment, quantmod

I've written the following function to autmoatically assess the effect of missing the best/worst days of trading ina  given stock. Unfortunately, one part of the function seems to fail:

```
library(quantmod)
    missingDays<- function(ticker,dmiss=10,type="best",period="days",fdate="2000-01-01",tdate=Sys.Date()) {
          getSymbols(ticker,from=fdate,to=tdate) #quantmod to pull ticker info
          d<-get(ls()[1])
          x<-as.data.frame(periodReturn(Cl(d),period=period))
          x<- x[order(x[1]),]
          if(type=="best") {
            (((mean(x[1:(length(x)-dmiss)],na.rm=TRUE)+1)^(251))-1)*100      #average daily return, annualized  
          } else {
            (((mean(x[dmiss:(length(x))],na.rm=TRUE)+1)^(251))-1)*100      #average daily return, annualized
          }  
        }
missingDays("^GSPC",10,type="best",period="daily",fdate="2000-01-01")
```

The error clearly happens in these two lines of code:

```
  d<-get(ls()[1])
  x<-as.data.frame(periodReturn(Cl(d),period=period))
```

This is very odd, because when I run this directly, rather than in a function, it works fine. It seems to not be able to identify `d` as an xts object.

My apologies if I've missed something obvious - I've been at this a while.

Much thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `getSymbols` like that inside a function.  Set `auto.assign=FALSE` and assign the output of `getSymbols` to `d` directly:

```
d <- getSymbols(ticker,from=fdate,to=tdate,auto.assign=FALSE)
```

This is all described in detail in `?getSymbols`.  I would encourage you to read it carefully.

---

UPDATE:

Now that I think about it a bit more, it would probably be better for the `missingDays` function to accept the output from a call to `getSymbols`.  Then you would avoid having to download the data for different sets of parameters.

```
missingDays <- function(symbol, dmiss=10, type="best", period="daily",
        fdate="2000-01-01", tdate=Sys.Date()) {
  x <- as.data.frame(periodReturn(Cl(symbol),period=period))
  x <- x[order(x[1]),]
  if(type=="best") {
    #average daily return, annualized
    (((mean(x[1:(length(x)-dmiss)],na.rm=TRUE)+1)^(251))-1)*100
  } else {
    #average daily return, annualized
    (((mean(x[dmiss:(length(x))],na.rm=TRUE)+1)^(251))-1)*100
  }
}
getSymbols("^GSPC", from="2000-01-01")
missingDays(GSPC)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `ls` is evaluating inside the function envir. Use `.GlobalEnv` to have it look it up in the global environment.

```
d <- get(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I'm not sure if the envir in get function is needed. But I guess it won't hurt.

HTH